# To check Consistency of an estimator

Tags: probability

Is  theta a consistent estimator and why?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrbVD.jpg)

Comment: Please take the time to post your question in a format that is easy to read for visitors of this post.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact consistent, though not central. Consider the limit og the estimator.